# How quickly can Large number of rows from HBase be read?

Tags: hbase

HBase is known for quick read and writes-- for instance, from shell.

However, suppose i have a really large dataset. I would like to quickly get say 500,000 rows with some shared characteristic. How quickly can i get this from HBase?

Comment: why don't you run a test yourself?

Comment: you tested scanners before?